# Travelling to America under a different name than before

Tags: usa

A few years ago I traveled to America under a different name to my birth name and had my fingerprints and retina scan taken I’ve since changed my name back to my birth name will this cause me a problem in returning to America

Comment: What is it "America"? Just US?

Comment: What is your citizenship, what were your access credentials (Visa, Esta, Residence Permit) and what country in America are we talking about.

Comment: hey, come on, nobody and i mean NOBODY says "America" to mean "the combination of North and South America." It's actually offensive when people pretend someone might be referring to Canada. Don't do that.

Comment: @KateGregory well native Anglophones use US and America interchangeably but speakers of Spanish sometimes differentiate. I agree the OP has an Anglo username so it is all Lombard Street to a China orange they mean the US.

Comment: Come on all, they even tagged USA

Comment: @KateGregory you might be surprised to find that there are other countries

Comment: @Blueriver trust me, I know that Canada is not the only country in the world. Your comment isn't helpful or useful

Comment: People keep it polite, we all know that America usually means USA but also that people sometimes mean something other than the most obvious. Both options are covered in the comments already.

Answer (score 8):

If you are open about the name change and that you have been in the USA, and under which name, the fact you changed your name is not a problem.

If you broke rules and would not be allowed under your previous name you have a very big chance you will not be allowed this time.
If you try to hide your previous visit and are found out on that a ban is likely and that will affect more than 'just' travel to the USA as many countries do not trust people who got a ban to enter a country.

With the USA you can or have to apply for a visa and if you are honest in the application you run little risk when travelling, but the USA does not guarantee you are allowed in with a visa.

While I have answered for the USA, in most countries it will work the same, only it is not always possible to apply for a visa when you come from a country of which the citizens do not usually need a visa. But in most countries it is that if you have a visa you are good to get in unless you did not disclose the name change and previous visit.